# How to pass an implicit value to an instance thats retrieved by guice

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, guice

Consider the following class:

```
class MyClass @Inject() (ws: WSClient)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext)
```

and the code that gets this class:

```
app.injector.instanceOf[MyClass]
```

From what i understand the guice injector, injects an `ExecutionContext` into that implicit ExecutionContext, but in some cases i would like to give that instance a different`ExecutionContext`

How am i supposed to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're mixing up two separated things: dependency injection (via guice - inside Play) and implicit parameters. In this specific case you're injecting `ws` while declaring a class that has one implicit parameter. See https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Declaring-runtime-DI-dependencies

Comment: Ok so how do i pass a value to that classes implicit parameter

Comment: You may want to read more about Scala implicit parameters. Here's a link (but you can find plenty) http://daily-scala.blogspot.it/2010/04/implicit-parameters.html

Comment: I guess there's more here than meets the eye. It seems like `Play` provides an implicit `ExecutionContext` to any guice-injected instance, though I can't still find where this behaviour is implemented or documented.

Answer (score 7):

You could mark an implicit parameter with annotation @Named and define a binding for the "named" ExecutionContext.

```
class MyClass @Inject() (ws: WSClient)
                        (implicit @Named("myEC") executionContext: ExecutionContext)
```

The binding:

```
package my.modules

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import com.google.inject.name.Names

class MyExecutionContextModule extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind(classOf[ExecutionContext]).annotatedWith(Names.named("myEC"))
      .to(classOf[MyExecutionContextImpl])
      // .toInstance(myExecutionContext)
  }
}
```

Then you need to enable the module in Play configuration

```
play.modules.enabled += "my.modules.MyExecutionContextModule"
```

See [Guice docs](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations#named) for more information about annotations. You can also define your own annotation or create a Module to bind implementation for your MyClass class (then it is better to make it a trait and implement it in a different class). The only Play specific thing here is that you need to enable module in config if you define one.